# React Translations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture, react-transition-group

I have situation where I need to create translation support for React application I have already created using **JSON** support like `react-i18n` but now I decided to create new functionality use adding HTML templates like it uses in PHP how can I Implement it and what do you think which way is more effective.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get what you mean with `like it uses in PHP` ?

Comment: I want to use  HTML templates and remove JSON support. That is to say for example I will use for `en` template `en.html` template  and show it in DOM. Is it possible ? or it isn`t best way?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is easier, as you not onpy have to return a seperate html you also have to return separate react components

Comment: I needed something similar, so perhaps this is useful to you too
https://dev.to/chadsteele/usetranslator-a-react-translation-hook-13of